# How can I loop through 2 Range-Objects in the same Loop in VBA for Excel?

Tags: excel, vba

I tried to comment in the Code below what I try to do. I know how to keep the selected Cells for the old value which got changed. It works with only one cell, but not more. I don't get it how I can loop through the 2 Range-Objects in the same For-Loop. I don't think it will work with a For-Each.

```
Dim OldValue As Range

Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
  Dim FirstFreeRow As Long
  Dim tCell As Variant
  Dim I As Integer
  
  If Sh.Name = "Changes" Then Exit Sub
  If Sh.Name = "Tabelle2" Then Exit Sub
  If Intersect(Target, Sh.Range("A2:Z550")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
  
  Application.EnableEvents = False
  
  For I = 0 To Target.Count 'Go through all changed Cells
  
  tCell = Target.Cells(I, 1)

  With Sheets("Changes")
    FirstFreeRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    With .Rows(ErsteFreieZeile) '.EntireRow
       .Cells(1) = tCell.EntireColumn.Cells(1)
       .Cells(2) = tCell.EntireRow.Cells(2)
       .Cells(3) = tCell.EntireRow.Cells(3)
       .Cells(4) = OldValue(I, 1).Value 'Put the old value in here
       .Cells(5) = tCell.Range("A1").Value
       .Cells(6) = Environ("username")
    End With
  End With

  Next I
  
  Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub

Public Sub Workbook_SheetSelectionChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)

Set OldValue = Target 'Save all selected Cells

End Sub
```

Sidequestion: If you use Cut and Paste then you don't have the old Value obviously, because you have a new selcted cell. Is there a way too? If not, doesn't matter.

Thanks.

**Edit:**
[I am not allowed yet to post images directly. So it is posted as a link instead. Apologies. The Images shows how the Changes are supposed to be documented.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JgegO.png)

Does this make it more clear? I only have "Tabelle 1". "Tabelle 2" is something else, doesn't matter here.

Comment: Correct my understanding. If there is any change in any sheet other than `Changes` and `Tabelle2` then you want to copy some cells to `Changes` sheet. If yes, can you post a screenshot of the sample data and also clearly mention which cells and from which column needs to be copied.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have several possibilities to loop over all cells of a Range:

A) Loop using Count (of cells)

```
Dim i As Long
For i = 1 To target.Count
    Debug.Print "Method A ", target(i).Address
Next
```

As you can see, you use only a single index into the range when you use this method

B) Loop over rows and columns

```
Dim row As Long, col As Long
For row = 1 To target.Rows.Count
    For col = 1 To target.Columns.Count
        Debug.Print "Method B ", target(row, col).Address
    Next col
Next row
```

Now you use 2 indizes into the range, the row and the column. Note that those indizes represent relative numbers, so if your range is "E5:G10", target(1, 1) is the first row and first column of that range, that is cell E5.

C) Using a foreach loop.

```
Dim cell As Range
For Each cell In target
    Debug.Print "Method C ", cell.Address
Next cell
```

In most cases that is the easiest way.

---

I see at least 2 issues in your code:
The first is that you use the first method (using count) for the loop but reads the cell from the target range using 2 indizes. If you have 3 rows by 4 colums in your range (so count = 12), you would read 12 cells from the first row which is not what you want.

Second is that you miss the `Set` keyword (and you declare `tCell` as Variant instead of `Range`. Now id `tCell = Target.Cells(I, 1)`, tCell will get the *content* of the Range. This will give you a runtime error later in your code (`tCell.EntireColumn` cannot work if tCell is a value).
In VBA, you need to use the keyword `Set` to assign a reference to an object to a variable: `Set tCell = Target.Cells(I, 1)`

Comment: Thanks, but if I use the first Method is says "Object doesn't support this properties or method" at "Target(i).Adress

Comment: Needs to be `Address`

Comment: Ah, yes, of course. Stupid me. Sorry :D